# How can I get a scroll bar in the right-bottom div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to lay out a web page that has three reasons - left, top right and bottom right. The left and bottom right regions should have scrollbars in them, and the entire page should fill the screen. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

I can get the scrollbars working properly around the left region. The problem is with the right regions - the horizontal scrollbar appears on the bottom-right region, as it should, but the vertical scrollbar appears on the entire page. Note that the bottom-right also has a vertical scroll bar, but it's disabled.

```css
#outer {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: none;
}

#left-col {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #ff85d4;
}

#left-large {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 5000px;
}

#right-col {
  height: 100vh;
}

#right-top {
  background-color: #abff64;
}

#right-bottom {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: #ccddff;
}

#right-bottom-inner {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="outer">
    <div class="col-9" id="left-col">
      <div id="left-large">
        Large left
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3" id="right-col">
      <div id="right-top">
        <p>
          Top 1
        </p>
        <p>
          Top 2
        </p>
        <p>
          Top 3
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="right-bottom">
        <div id="right-bottom-inner">
          Right bottom inner
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the bottom-right region have its own scrollbars?

Comment: You're going to have to define a height much like you did for the others... I think using CSS grid would be much easier here than using Bootstrap but that's just my personal opinion

Comment: How will a grid fix this issue?

Comment: I mean this is literally a grid you got there as your layout... :)

Comment: It is, but a grid or a flexbox do not behave better when it comes to scrollbars in items, do they?

Comment: It absolutely would since you give the outer wrapper a fixed height everything inside would have to adhere to the grid.

Comment: I tried it, and the scrollbar doesn't appear in the relevant grid item unless I explicitly give it a height.

Comment: I added an answer for you to show you how easy it could be with CSS grid. Hope it helps

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you can make the `right-top` box grow for as long as the content is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments this is another way to do this with CSS grid which seems like the perfect tool for something this ... "gridy" :)

I gave all the boxes plenty of space you can scroll... adjust at will.

Update: I made the `right-top` box `max-content` and grow for as long as the content is while giving the `right-bottom` box a min height of `20px`.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1.6fr 0.4fr;
    grid-template-rows: max-content minmax(20px, 1fr);
    gap: 1rem;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.wrapper-inner {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 2000px;
}

.left,
.right-top,
.right-bottom {
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.left {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    background: hotpink;
}

.right-top {
    background: lime;
}

.right-bottom {
    background: skyblue;    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
        Large left
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="right-top">
        <p>
            Top 1
        </p>
        <p>
            Top 2
        </p>
        <p>
            Top 3
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-bottom">
        <div class="wrapper-inner">
            Right bottom inner
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

flex is magic
CSS

```
/*Allow children to auto fixed height*/
#right-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#right-top {
  height: fit-content; /*Only use essential*/
}

#right-bottom {
  overflow: scroll; /*See child content*/
  height:100%; /*use all remain height*/
}
```

Comment: This assumes I want to divide the heights 20% / 80 %. I want the top to be dynamic depending on its content, and the bottom to fill the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a scrollbar on any block element, you'll need to set a fixed height and include an `overflow-x:scroll` or `overflow-y:scroll` property depending on where you want the scrollbar to appear.

If you want a horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow-x:scroll;`, if you want a vertical scrollbar, use `overflow-y:scroll;`

Answer (score -1):

Seeing that the height needs to be explicit (either as percentage or a fixed number), I couldn't find a CSS-only solution.

Instead I used a `ResizeObserver` to track changes to the size of the `right-col` and `right-top` elements (in my actual problem, the right-top element changes in size), calculated the right-bottom element (`right-col.height - right-top.height` basically), and applied it as a dynamic `style` on the `right-bottom` element.

Not pretty but it's working.

I tried using a CSS grid, too (instead of bootstrap altogether), but without explicitly specifying the height of the right bottom element, the scrollbars misbehaved there, as well.

Comment: flex not necessarily https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643450/15859431